# VSFTPD on windows and other issue

Tags: ssh, ftp, sftp, vsftpd

I have to build an vsftpd compatible ftp client. I am not sure about which protocol vsftpd follows, sftp or ftps, I am guessing sftp as i could connect some vsftpd client with port 21(ftp) and 22(sftp) but not 990(ftps).

Now I have to communicate with vsftpd compatible ftp server using C#.NET. Can somebody help me find out some good open source sftp client.

I also need to setup some sftp server on windows. Is there any opensource sftp server.

Thanks.

Comment: vsftp is an FTP server. It doesn't do SFTP.

Comment: Hmm... That means vstpd is just a server which can do ftp and ftps (I just found this) and sftp is included in openssl, it only emulates ftp. Am I right?

Comment: You are right about VSFTP. I wouldn't say that sftp emulates ftp, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

vsftpd supports FTP and FTPS, so you need an FTP/FTPS .NET client. It isn't open source but one option is [edtFTPnet/PRO](http://www.enterprisedt.com/products/edtftpnetpro/overview.html). It does FTP, FTPS and SFTP (in case you ever need the latter).

If you want an SFTP server for Windows, try [CompleteFTP](http://www.enterprisedt.com/products/completeftp/overview.html). It supports FTP, FTPS, SFTP and SCP on Windows.